# Launching external Camera app from my WP8 app

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, camera, uri-scheme

I want to launch the native Nokia Camera app from my app (or any other Camera app like "Nokia Camera", "CameraPro"). I searched its possible through the URI schemes. I searched a lot but could not find the URI schemes of the above mentioned Camera apps.

Any expert advice will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do it with,
    CameraCaptureTask ccTask=new CameraCaptureTask();
On button click just write,
    ccTask.Show();

It will allow you to capture image only & save it to media library.

So simple, isn't it.
Hope this helps.
Happy coding